# converting array contents to http query

Tags: php

I have array like this one.

```
$fields = array(
            'user[facebook_gender]' => urlencode("female"),
            'user[facebook_likes]' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string=rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

then I get

```
user[facebook_gender]=female&user[facebook_likes]=Array
```

It just show "Array", however I want to show the content of Array,

Comment: What is your question? How to turn an `array` into a string? How to create a url from an `array`?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `serialize` function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

For example:

```
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
  if (is_array($value)) $value = serialize($value);
  $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$fields_string=rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

Note that you have to use `unserialize()` on your target site, to make use of the value again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `http_build_query` does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use implode on the array:

```
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    if(is_array($value))
    {
         $value = implode($value,",");
    }
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$fields_string=rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```